# Matter brought by you to my notice / matter brought to my notice by you

Tags: prepositions

> Why wasn't the matter brought by you to my notice ?

Or

> Why wasn't the matter brought to my notice by you ?

Perhaps the second sentence is better than first but is the structure of sentence grammatically correct in both the sentences ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of your sentences are grammatically correct, however more idiomatic would be to use

> **attention**

instead of

> **notice**
>
> Why wasn't the matter brought by you to my **attention** ?
>   Why wasn't the matter brought to my **attention** by you ?

and yes, the second one is better because in the ***Law of Order of Importance***, the more important points get mentioned first, by mentioning "**attention**" before "**you**" more focus is on "**attention**" since the inherent question is "Why wasn't the matter brought to my **attention**?" and not "Why wasn't the matter brought by you *(to me)*?".

In the case of "Why didn't you bring this to my attention?" there is more focus on **you** and implicitly means "Why did someone else bring this to my attention?"

Comment: Actually I can't use attention, its a question asked in my exam for active passive conversion. Sentence given was - Why didn't you bring the matter to my notice ? I had to choose from A) Why wasn't the matter brought by you to my notice ? B) why wasn't the matter brought to my notice.

Comment: @user212388 So, unlike the way it is stated in the question, option B didn't mention "you" at all?

Comment: @SteveES Yes that's why answer given in book is option A . I inserted "you" in my thread because I didn't want answer for my exam question which I had in my book  but I wanted to know if there was any grammatically or any other difference in placement of 'you' in two different positions.

Comment: @user212388 OK, I see. Are you also asking whether there is any difference in meaning/interpretation etc. between the two? If so, please can you edit your question to say that? And maybe define a bit more what you mean by "better"?

Comment: @SteveES Sorry I may sound inane but I don't know how to explain that second sentence sounds better but Peter too has mentioned in his answer that second one is better.

Comment: @user212388 Please see edit in my answer